# Spread values after certain index

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

I am trying to spread array values into an object after a certain index 3 (column_4).

```
const array = ['Column_5', 'Column 6', 'Column 7']

const object = {
    column_1: '',
    column_2: 'Status',
    column_3: 'Master',
    column_4: 'Locale',
    ...array
}
```

At the moment, Column 5/6/7 appear at the start:

```
{
    0: "Column_5",
    1: "Column 6", 
    2: "Column 7", 
    column_1: "", 
    column_2: "Status", 
    column_3: "Master", 
    column_4: "Locale"
}
```

But I need them to appear in numerical order. Any ideas? I've tried using Ramda's insert method without any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const array = ['column_5', 'column_6', 'column_7']

const object = {
    column_1: '',
    column_2: 'Status',
    column_3: 'Master',
    column_4: 'Locale',
    ...array.reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc[item] = item;
      return acc;
   }, {}),   
}

console.log(object);
```

Comment: This solution works great after the small edit: `acc[item] = item`